# Convergence of a bounded continuous function whose derivative vanishes at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

Let $x(t):[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function.
Suppose $|x'(t)| \le Ce^{-t}$ (which implies that $\sup_t |x(t)| < \infty$).

> Can we claim that $\lim_{t\to \infty} x(t) = x^*$ for some $x^*$?

I think this is true, however, I cannot rigorously prove or disprove it.

Any answers/comments/suggestions will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Using Mean Value Theorem,  show $x(n)$ is a Cauchy sequence...

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Actually, I was able to show that (from the uniform boundedness) there exists a sequence that converges to some point $x^*$, i.e., $\lim_{k \to \infty} x(t_k) = x^*$. But this only shows one discrete path and wasn't clear to see how to proceed next.

Comment: It seems that for large $t$ since the derivative is very small so that $x(t)$ cannot change too much. Thus, I think I can use this fact to show a contradiction assuming $\lim_{t\to \infty} x(t) \ne x^*$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Further hint: $|x(n+1) - x(n)| \le C e^{-n}$.

Comment: I thought I got it, but it seems it isn't. I tried to show the sequence $\{x(n)\}$ is Cauchy using your hint. But, it seems that for $m > n$, we have $|x(m) - x(n)| \le C|m-n|e^{-n}$. Thus, it is unclear to see whether this sequence is Cauchy. Since $m$ could grow fast enough so that the RHS may not be small...

Comment: But if $|x(n+1) - x(n)| \le C e^{-n}$, $|x(m) - x(n)| \le C (e^{-n} + e^{-n-1} + \ldots)$.

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you so so much for your help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use Cantor's Intersection Theorem:

> Suppose $(A_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ is a sequence of closed subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ (or indeed, any complete metric space) such that $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$, and
>   $$\operatorname{diam} A_n := \sup_{x, y \in A_n} |x - y| \to 0$$
>   as $n \to \infty$. Then,
>   $$\left|\bigcap_{n \in \Bbb{N}} A_n\right| = 1.$$

Let $A_n = \overline{x[n, \infty)}$. Then clearly $A_n$ is closed, and $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$ (this is true for any real function). We can use the bound on the derivative to show that $\operatorname{diam} A_n \to 0$.

Suppose $t \in (n, \infty)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
x(t) - x(n) &= \int_n^t x'(s) \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&\le \int_n^t |x'(s)| \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&\le \int_n^t Ce^{-s} \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= C(e^{-n} - e^{-t}) \\
&\le Ce^{-n} \to 0.
\end{align*}

This shows us that elements of $x[n, \infty)$ can be no more than $Ce^{-n}$ apart, which is also true of the closure $A_n$. Hence, by the Cantor Intersection Theorem, there exists a unique $x^* \in \Bbb{R}$ such that

$$x^* \in \bigcap_{n \in \Bbb{N}} A_n.$$

I claim that this is the limit we need. For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $n \ge N \implies |Ce^{-n}| < \varepsilon$, hence
$$t \ge N \implies x(t), x^* \in A_N \implies |x(t) - x^*| \le |Ce^{-N}| < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: You need more than just differentiability to say $x(t) - x(n) = \int_n^t x'(s)\; ds$.